# Developer Script error

Tags: apex

I got an apex script error email as i have been set as the last modified by for that apex class.But i have never updated the class,so how did the last modified by field get updated by my name?Is there any process automation /workflow that set affects the last modified by?

Answer (score 1):

There's no workflow rule or process that would have affected this field. It may have been part of a synchronization using the Force.com IDE, Migration Toolkit, Gearset, etc. Just because you didn't change the content does not mean that your user did not perform a "change" as defined by the last modified by field.

Comment: Gearset -- a product we use extensively - nice to see it being ack'd